# Passing a callable to a object that builds some kind of multi-index container

Tags: c++11, lambda, c++14, callable, generic-lambda

I'm trying to write a container that is able to categories objects and store pointers for which a categorisation function is true.

My problem is, that it does not compile and since I'm inexperienced in regard to callables like `std::function` or `lambdas`, I'm not sure how to fix it.

I want such a container, since I've the need to get some "Categories" often - and this makes it easy to cache the results. Especially if, in this example, the `Dog`s change their `sound`, the Categories can simply be recreated (since the callable is still there).

What is more, I'm interested in a solution that delivers good performance. As I read, `std::function`s are unlikely to be `inline`d. Is there a way to deliver `inline`d-performance?

The compiler says:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:51:108: error: no matching function for call to 'CategoryContainer<Dog>::addCategory(CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories, main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>)'
     dogs.addCategory( CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories::Wuff, [](auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="Wuff";} );

main.cpp:39:10: note: candidate: void CategoryContainer<T>::addCategory(CategoryContainer<T>::Categories, std::function<bool()>) [with T = Dog]
     void addCategory(Categories cat, std::function<bool()> f) {
main.cpp:39:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>' to 'std::function<bool()>'

main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:52:71: error: expected '{' before '(' token
     dogs.addCategory( CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories::WauWau, []()(auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="WauWau";} );

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:52:72: error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'
     dogs.addCategory( CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories::WauWau, []()(auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="WauWau";} );
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class Dog
{
public:
    std::string makeSound() { return _sound; }
    void setSound(std::string sound) { _sound=sound; }
private:
    std::string _sound = "Wuff";
};

template<class T>
class CategoryContainer
{
public:
    using objectContainer = std::vector<T>;
    using pointerContainer = std::vector<T*>;

    enum class Categories { Wuff, WauWau }; // Dogs are e.g. destinguished by the sound they make.

    struct Category {
        std::function<bool()> func;
        pointerContainer pointers;
        Category(std::function<bool()> f, objectContainer& data) : func(f) {
            for(auto& i : data)
                if( func(i) )
                    pointers.emplace_back(&i);
        }
    };

    CategoryContainer(size_t n) {
        data.resize(n); // Construct so many dogs.
    }

    void addCategory(Categories cat, std::function<bool()> f) {
        indexed[cat] = Category(f, data);
    }

private:
    objectContainer data;
    std::unordered_map<Categories, Category> indexed;
};

int main()
{
    CategoryContainer<Dog> dogs(10);
    dogs.addCategory( CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories::Wuff, [](auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="Wuff";} );
    dogs.addCategory( CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories::WauWau, []()(auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="WauWau";} );
}
```

Comment: An important point and still unanswered part is, how the compiler handles this situation. An addition to that point is very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `[](auto& d){return d.makeSound()=="Wuff";}` as a functor but `addCategory` is declared as

```
void addCategory(Categories cat, std::function<bool()> f) {
```

So the functor is expected to take zero arguments but actually takes  Instead of `one.std::function<bool()>` you should use `std::function<bool(const T&)>`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Alexey Guseynov (+1), your `func()` in `Category` receive a `T` object.

So, as suggested, should be `std::function<bool(T const &)>`.

And you have to correct this in three points:

1) `std::function<bool()> func;` become `std::function<bool(T const &)> func;`

2) `Category(std::function<bool()> f, objectContainer& data) : func(f)` become `Category(std::function<bool(T const &)> f, objectContainer& data) : func(f)`

3) `void addCategory(Categories cat, std::function<bool()> f)` become `void addCategory(Categories cat, std::function<bool(T const &)> f)`.

But isn't enough.

Now the `makeSound()` method of `Dog` is used with const `Dog` instantiations inside your lambda funtions. So `makeSound()` (that doesn't modify the object) should be modified in a `const` method

```
std::string makeSound() const { return _sound; }
```

At this point I have some errors because `Dogs` is incompatible with `std::unordered_map` because (if I understand correctly) there isn't a specialization for `std::hash<CategoryContainer<Dog>::Categories>`

But, to avoid this problem, if you can change the

```
std::unordered_map<Categories, Category> indexed;
```

in a ordered `std::map` (adding `#include <map>` too)

```
std::map<Categories, Category> indexed;
```

and if you change, in `addCategory()`, the row

```
indexed[cat] = Category(f, data);
```

that give error for reasons (involving constructors) that I don't want investigate further, with

```
indexed.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                std::forward_as_tuple(cat),
                std::forward_as_tuple(f, data));
```

you shoul'd be able to compile your example.